# I wrote a KMeans class but the results look strange, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I was following along with Joel Grus' "Data Science from Scratch" and using it wrote my own KMeans code (swapping Joel's functions for numpy ones etc.). The code below converges and finds centroids, but they are almost always in the center of the feature space. Upon further investigation, it looks like the while loop exits on the second iteration (i.e. no changes are detected). I can't figure out why though, what have I done wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs


features, true_labels = make_blobs(
        n_samples=200,
        centers=3,
        cluster_std=2.75,
        random_state=42
    )

class KMeans:
    def __init__(self, k):
        self.k = k
        self.means = None
        self.assignments = None
        
    def classify(feat, centroids):
        distances = [np.linalg.norm(feat - cent) for cent in centroids]
        label = np.argwhere(distances == min(distances))
        return label
    
    def cluster_means(features, assignments, k):
        clusters = [features[self.assingments == cluster,:] for cluster in range(k)]
        cluster_means = np.array([np.mean(clusters[i], axis=0) for i in range(k)])
        return cluster_means
    
    def train(self, features):
        self.assignments = np.random.randint(low=0, high=self.k, size=len(features))
        while True:
            #find the centroids of the k classes
            self.means = cluster_means(features, self.assignments, self.k)    
            new_assignments = [classify(feat, self.means) for feat in features]
            
            #get number of changes
            nChanges = len([x1 for x1, x2 in zip(self.assignments, new_assignments) if x1 != x2])
            
            if nChanges == 0:
                return
            
            self.assignments = new_assignments
            #self.means = cluster_means(features, self.assignments, k)
            print(f"changed: {nChanges} / {len(features)}")

km = KMeans(k=3)
km.train(features)
km.means
```

[image: Centroids don't move from the centre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, sometimes you just need to post on here to end up answering your own question while you write it!

Anyway, the reason it was breaking on the second iteration was that the list comprehensions needed to be converted into numpy arrays to be able to use the np.argmin() in classify() and to properly count the number of changes for nChanges.

Here's a working solution

```
class KMeans:
    def __init__(self, k):
        self.k = k
        self.means = None
            
    def classify(feat, centroids):
        distances = np.array([np.linalg.norm(feat - cent) for cent in centroids])
        label = np.argmin(distances)
        return label

    def cluster_means(features, assignments, k):
        clusters = [features[assignments == cluster,:] for cluster in range(k)]
        cluster_means = np.array([np.mean(clusters[i], axis=0) for i in range(k)])
        return cluster_means

    def train(self, features):
        assignments = np.random.randint(low=0, high=self.k, size=len(features))
        while True:
            #find the centroids of the k classes
            self.means = self..cluster_means(features, assignments, self.k)    
            new_assignments = np.array([self.classify(feat, self.means) for feat in features])
            
            #get number of changes
            nChanges = len([x1 for x1, x2 in zip(assignments, new_assignments) if x1 != x2])
            
            if nChanges == 0:
                return
            else:
                assignments = new_assignments
                self.means = self.cluster_means(features, assignments, self.k)
            print(f"changed: {nChanges} / {len(features)}")
                

km = KMeans(k=3)
km.train(features)
km.means

sns.scatterplot(x=km.means[:,0], y=km.means[:,1], color='red')
sns.scatterplot(x=features[:,0], y=features[:,1], hue=true_labels)
```

[image: Centroids now where they should be!]